# converting C# to java

Tags: c#, java

```
   static FreeDutyProductManager()

    {

       string fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["freeDutyProductFile"];

       if (!File.Exists(fileName))
       {
           throw new FileNotFoundException("File can't not find:" +fileName);
       }

       freeDutyProduct = new Hashtable();
       TextReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));
       string line = string.Empty;

       IList<string> productList = null;
       while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           if (line.Trim()== string.Empty)
           {
               continue;
           }
           if (line.Trim().EndsWith(":"))
           {
               productList = new List<string>();
               freeDutyProduct.Add(line.Replace(":", ""),productList);
           }
           else
           {
               productList.Add(line.Trim());
           }
       }
   }
```

I want to convert this to JAVA, but java is warning me about hashtable  Null pointer access: The variable productList can only be null at this location.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You should probably post Java code then.

Comment: Right.  If you are having trouble with your Java code, post that code and explain where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

productList starts out null and only sometimes get assigned.

```
       if (line.Trim().EndsWith(":"))
       {
           productList = new List<string>();
           freeDutyProduct.Add(line.Replace(":", ""),productList);
       }
       else
       {
           productList.Add(line.Trim());
       }
```

Why not do the new List right where you declare the variable?